# NATing ports selection using hardware detection

Tags: iptables, nat

I have a linux box to be used as a router with a wlan port in AP mode. The internet input to the board may come from either an eth port (WAN mode) or another wlan port. There is also VPN running that is optional. Also there are more eth ports to be used in LAN mode.

Now, i'm looking for a way to detect (using a script) what is my current hardware configuration i.e whether internet is coming from a wired eth interface or from a wlan interface and what is the name of that interface (since there are multiple wlan/eth ports in the hardware).  I need this info, since during NATing in ip-tables, the commands need to change as per internet source interface name. Also, if VPN is enabled, NATing commands will change to tun0 as the internet source. How do i script all this detection based.
I have the setup running fine with manual changes to ip-tables, hostapd, udhcpd etc everytime hardware config changes, but i need to automate this stuff now.

Help appreciated !

Pushy